# No Access Audit found Ranger

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I am working on Apache Ranger to enable data security across my Hadoop platform, which is working fine but I am not able to see Access Audit on Ranger Portal.
[image: Audit Image]
I have enabled Audit to DB, Audit to HDFS and Audit provider summary as well for respective components on ambari.

Please help me to see Access Audit on Ranger Portal.

Answer (score 0):

check the namenode log (normally under /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/...-namenode.log) and see if the driver of your DB can be found or if an exception is thrown. If the latter is the case, add the driver JAR to e.g. */usr/share/java/* to make sure the driver class is available.

Answer (score 0):

Had met the same problem.

Followed every instruction but the hdfs plugin didn't take effect.

Solved by upgrading hadoop from 2.6.3 to 2.7.2.

As in [apach ranger](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/Apache+Ranger+0.5.0+Installation#ApacheRanger0.5.0Installation-EnablingRangerHDFSPlugins) offical site, it says ranger 0.5 only works with hadoop 2.7+.